# In DRF(django-rest-framework), null value in column "author_id" violates not-null constraint. What should i do?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I made django project through DRF.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2cxY.png)

From that window, i clicked post so then it did not worked.

**traceback**

```
#I almost omitted other codes
Environment:

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/comments/

Django Version: 1.9.7
Python Version: 3.5.2

Traceback:

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /comments/
Exception Value: null value in column "author_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (2, comment1, 2016-08-03 13:30:59.536186+00, null, null).
```

**serializers.py**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    posts = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(many=True, view_name='post-detail', read_only=True)
    comments = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(many=True, view_name='comment-detail', read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url','id', 'pk', 'username', 'email', 'comments', 'posts', 'author')

class CommentSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    author = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='author.username')
    post = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='post.title')
    highlight = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='comment-highlight', format='html')
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('url','id', 'pk', 'post', 'author', 'text','highlight')
```

**models.py**

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('blog.Post', related_name='related_comments')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='related_commentwriter')
    text = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

Additionally, i'm using django rest auth.

Why this error comes? How to solve this?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could not create Comment instance with null in `author` field. 
For fix it you can add author when you create new comment

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
...................

def create(self, validated_data):
    validated_data['author'] = self.context['request'].user
    return super(CommentSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
```

The same with `post` field.